# Application OutOfMemory after "resume"

Tags: java, garbage-collection

I have an application with this structure:

```
Main Thread -> ScheduleAtFixedRate1 -> ScheduleAtFixedRate3
                                    -> ScheduleAtFixedRate4
            -> ScheduleAtFixedRate2
```

The main thread is the thread with `main` method. Which is starting 2 ScheduleAtFixedRate(1 & 2).

The ScheduleAtFixedRate1 is starting another 2 ScheduleAtFixedRate(3 & 4).

The ScheduleAtFixedRate2 is a thread which is requesting(at a fixed rate) from a server some data and in this data is a variable `pause` which is pausing the program.

When `pause` is true, the ScheduleAtFixedRate1 is `close(true)`ing ScheduleAtFixedRate 3 & 4 and instead of executing the entire block of code, it is just checking the state of `pause` and `return`.

The program is starting with jvm argument `-XX:+UseZGC` and everything runs perfectly.

The problem appears when I pause the program and keep it for a very long time(hours). After resuming, the ScheduleAtFixedRate1 is starting ScheduleAtFixedRate 3 & 4 and everything works, for few seconds. After, the program crash with `OutOfMemoryException in thread-x`.

If I keep the program on pause for a short time (few minutes) is not crashing. The more I keep it on pause, the more chances to crash. So, sometimes crashes, sometimes not.

The program has allocated 2GB, but is using an average of 800MB while runs.

For me looks like `ZGC` is not doing his job after a long pause. But I don't know how to fix it.

If someone can know what can be the real cause and maybe has a solution.

The program is running with java-17

P.S. If it is not very clear, please ask for more details. I can't share the project.

Comment: It's hard to say without the actual code of said tasks. Please share it in the question, so we can reproduce. I would guess that the problem may be because the executor is trying to execute all the missed tasks one after the other and may be you have a memory leak, or some other memory problem that make your memory usage rise under such conditions.

Comment: @AndrésAlcarraz Actually I think you gave me the hint. During this pause I have a `thread.sleep(15_000)`. I think during this time, the future tasks are putted in queue. And longer the pause is, the bigger queue become. And when it's resumed it start all of them one by one, without the rate. I observed that when I resume it, runs more fast then usual, but didn't thinked to that. Thank you.